# How can i add a Visual Studio 2008 project to the staging area in git

Tags: git, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2008

Am trying to track my visual studio 2008 project with git, however when i run

```
git add *
```

Git complains by firing the error below

> error: open("2ndproject.ncb"): Permission denied
>   error: unable to index file 2ndproject.ncb
>   fatal: adding files failed

It seems as though Git can't access the file `2ndproject.ncb`, and I can't afford tracking the rest of my files leaving this one behind. I've tried adding full control access for the file `2ndproject.ncb` but Git can't still access the file.  I highly welcome any possible insights on how I can solve the problem.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should *never* add .ncb files under version control. Those are Visual Studio Intellisense files used for code autocompletion etc. The .ncb file is always locked by the running VS instance, recreated on every build, prone to corruption and therefore it's not portable. Create a proper [.gitignore](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore) file before versioning a VS project. VS creates *lots* of build artifacts that don't belong under version control.